# Array length -1 in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Considering an array,has say 5 elements

```
"${#my_array[@]}"
```

As this gives the array size of 5. How to get less then 1 (i.e. array_size-1)

```
 "${#my_array[@]}-1"

  #and

 "${#my_array[@]-1}"
```

doesn't work

Comment: [U&L: How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/273492)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is reference the array from the end, use negative indexes.

```
$: my_array=( a b c d e )
$: echo "${#my_array[@]}"
5
$: echo "${my_array[-1]}"
e
$: echo "${my_array[-2]}"
d
```

If you just *need* the numeric reference of the last element, please carefully read the links provided, but here's an example.

```
$: lastIndex=$(( ${#my_array[@]} - 1 ))
$: echo $lastIndex
4
$: echo ${my_array[$lastIndex]}
e
```

or without the `$`,

```
$: echo ${my_array[lastIndex]} # arithmetic context recognizes varnames
e
```

Comment: Note that the index of an numerically indexed array is an arithmetic expression, so you can do this: `${my_array[ ${#my_array[@]} - 2 ]}`, but the negative indices are much more readable.

Comment: Also, because the index is an arithmetic expression, you can omit the `$`: `${my_array[lastIndex]}`